# How would I prepare for long distance biking?

Tags: bicycling, long-distance

I'm getting ready to go to college in about 7 weeks. But, it's too far to walk and if I was to take the bus, it would use the money they give me for transportation. I'm also not allowed to take a taxi due to them giving me money to travel, so, I thought why not a bike? But, the bike ride is 2 hours, so, what should I do to prepare for the bike rides?
And, what should I watch out for?

P.S it the closest college to me.

Comment: Is it 2h for single trip or 2h to ride back & forth between the college. Also what distance are we talking about here (in miles/km)

Comment: As a side, you said "the money they give me for transportation". Aren't you meant to use this money for bus tickets and the like?

Comment: this one is to user999 it's currently 10 miles

Comment: Josaur the money they have geivin me has to be spent on train ticket to get there and as we all know train arnt that cheap as a train would cast a 5 pound ther and 5 pounds back so that will last so 3 and a half days

Comment: @User999999 it may not seem far but im not the fitst guy and it will take a whle to get faster at the time and minite google reccomend a certian speed that i will not be capable of keep for that long so ill have to stop alot and go at a slower pace

Comment: @DaveSmith I'm not judging mate :) . It just sketches a clearer picture for us to help you

Comment: @User999999 no problem, sorry if it made it seem i was upset or angry with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first how fit you are ? how experienced you are on bike ? what kind of bike you have ?  it is ready or enough for that use ?

You should just ride and see for you self what you are capable of. After that you can plan better your training. You can chose a "bike friendly" route around your town better if it have long uphills. It should be longer that your commute. Also a right bike to do the job it would help a lot and it is really important how save is your route. It take some time to get used to drive between cars. Be aware of state of the roads of your route and how fast cars go there and how good it is the visibility. Try get aware of most dangerous points: tight turns whit out visibility, cross roads, thin country roads (where people drive like crazy)...

I did the same that you at first try was breath dead after 400m. But in few weeks I was making 18km around my town few times per week. In my case my institute was just 5km away so it took me 20min to get there but I needed to get in some shape to push the pedals at a decent rithm.

It is said that bike it is the most efficient way of transport but it is un natural for your body. You need to get used to it.

Comment: im not the fitest person on earth a 4/10 but ive stared gym last week so im hopeing that will help alot. im a 10/10 at a steady pace but can only go for around 30 at my current state i have some type of bmx i brought second hand so i dont really know much about it and ill will take note of the safest roads to travle on but to get to this college i have to go down a a motor way for around 7 miles and i live ina rural area so as you can guess there going to be a alot of "crazy drivers"  I currently have all the safty gear as ill need to head out quite early sorry about grammar im in a rush

Comment: I am sorry but I dont catch what 10/10,4/10 mean. bmx it is not the best bike for it maybe even the worse as it is made for doing tricks not riding for long some even come without a seat having also low gear cog ratio and small wheels. The good thing is that 7 miles is not much for a bike. It depend of the bike but with geared bike you provable can easily do it in 40min or less after some weeks or mounts.

Comment: i mean the 4/10 is me trying to give you a fitness level so to make it easire im not the fitest person in the world im slightly above avarge wheght for a 6,1" guy the 10/10 was refering to how good i am on a im am on a bike to make it simpaler im very good on a bike and what bike do you suggest